# scipy.fft.ifftn of complex pyopecl.array

Tags: fft, pyopencl

I'm trying to add two 3D complex arrays on gpu using pyopencl and then perform inverse fast Fourier transform of it result. But I have a mistake, which I do not really understand. Any advices on increasing code performance would be great.

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np
import os
from scipy.fftpack import fftn, ifftn
import pyopencl.array as cl_array
from pyopencl.elementwise import ElementwiseKernel
os.environ['PYOPENCL_COMPILER_OUTPUT'] = '1'

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

Lx = 50
Ly = 50
Lz = 1

M1f = np.ones((2 * Lx - 1, 2 * Ly - 1, 2 * Lz -                               1)).astype(np.float32)
M2f = np.ones((2 * Lx - 1, 2 * Ly - 1, 2 * Lz - 1)).astype(np.float32)

FM1 = fftn(M1f)
FM2 = fftn(M2f)

res_cpu = FM1 + FM2

print(ifftn(res_cpu))

FM1_gpu = cl_array.to_device(queue,np.reshape(FM1, (2*Lx-1)*(2*Ly-  1)*(2*Lz-1)).astype(np.complex64))
FM2_gpu = cl_array.to_device(queue,np.reshape(FM2, (2*Lx-1)*(2*Ly-1)*(2*Lz-1)).astype(np.complex64))

complex_add = ElementwiseKernel(ctx,
        "float *x, "
        "float *y, "
        "float *z",
        "z[i] = x[i] + y[i]",
        "complex_add")

add_gpu = cl_array.empty_like(FM1_gpu)
complex_add(FM1_gpu, FM2_gpu, add_gpu)

res_gpu = np.zeros((2*Lx-1, 2*Ly-1, 2*Lz-1)).astype(np.complex64)
res_gpu = np.reshape(add_gpu, (2*Lx-1, 2*Ly-1, 2*Lz-1))

print(ifftn(res_gpu))
```

I expect to have a true value of ifft of 2 complex arrays, which were add in gpu, but instead of it i get the result:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/heisenberg/Desktop/НИР/FM/math/GPU/loopsum.py", line 43, in
>   
>       print(ifftn(res_gpu))   File "/home/heisenberg/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/fftpack/basic.py",
>   line 670, in ifftn
>       return _raw_fftn_dispatch(x, shape, axes, overwrite_x, -1)   File "/home/heisenberg/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/fftpack/basic.py",
>   line 628, in _raw_fftn_dispatch
>       tmp = _asfarray(x)   File "/home/heisenberg/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/fftpack/basic.py",
>   line 136, in _asfarray
>       return numpy.asarray(x, dtype=x.dtype)   File "/home/heisenberg/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py",
>   line 538, in asarray
>       return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order) TypeError: must be real number, not Array
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! As `res_gpu = np.reshape(add_gpu, (2*Lx-1, 2*Ly-1, 2*Lz-1))` is called, the pyopencl.array `add_gpu` is cast into a numpy array... I don't know if it is the problem, but you can try to use the `get()` method of the class [pyopencl.array](https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/array.html) instead. Indeed, it transfers the contents of self into ary or a newly allocated numpy.ndarray. If ary is given, it must have the same shape and dtype. Something like `res_gpu = np.reshape(add_gpu.get(), (2*Lx-1, 2*Ly-1, 2*Lz-1))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works